# How to display only some part of the data from  DB into a list view

Tags: android, database, listview, simplecursoradapter

Here is my code to retriev the data from db to a listview.

```
private void fillData() {

    Cursor c = viewDB.fetchAllRows();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { ViewComplaintsDataDB.KEY_NUMBER,
            ViewComplaintsDataDB.KEY_DESCRIPTION,
            ViewComplaintsDataDB.KEY_LOGGEDBY }; //these three are the fields in my db

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.com_num, R.id.com_desc , R.id.user }; //these three are the textview id's in my listitem.xml file 

    SimpleCursorAdapter simple = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listitem, c, from, to);

    setListAdapter(simple);

}
```

This is working.

There is a lot of data in each row under the second column in my DB. How can i display only 50 characters of data from the second field to the listview. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the maxLength atribute from the textView to 50.

`<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="50"></TextView>`

Comment: i want to append three dots (...) for the text above 50 characters. How can i append ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that could be a phone related issue. I don't get three dots in the emulator, so every phone could handle this in their own way.

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to `ArrayAdapter` instead of `SimpleCursorAdapter` and fetch the data required to show from the `DB` and set it to the adapter....